# C# Events in Unity

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts attached to two different game objects, and in one of them I have an `Action` like this:

```
public class EnemeyController : MonoBehavior
{
    internal Action EnemyWaveKilled;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        // If hit by a bullet, kill and raise the event
        EnemyWaveKilled?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

In my other script's `Start` method, I try to subscribe to this event in this way:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehavior
{
    internal int PlayerLevel;

    private void Start()
    {
        _enemyController = GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy").GetComponent<EnemyController>();
        _enemyController.EnemyWaveKilled += () => PlayerLevel++;
    }
}
```

I have 3 game objects all with tag `Enemy` in the scene.

Now, it seems that my `GameController` somehow randomly subscribes to the event.

To be more accurate, if I print `EnemyWaveKilled.Target` in my `EnemyController` class's `Update()` method, it displays one line saying it's `GameController` and two lines saying it's `null`)

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Just a FYI, unity has [its own wrappers around events](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) that plays nicer with serialization, you may want to look in to them. Also, your Edit should be an answer, not an edit. Unless you still have a question?

Comment: Thank you. I will check your link, and also I will update the question

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's happening. I have 3 objects with the same tag, but I'm only subscribing to one of them; that's why I see the two `null` values (and a single non-`null` value)